# Install Ubuntu 12.10 on Windows Using Windows Installer

Tags: installation, 12.10, wubi

I'm presently using Windows XP. When trying to follow instructions for an installation with a DVD, my system shows the following error:
[image: Ubuntu Installer error]

How can I install Ubuntu if I have this problem?

Comment: Could you post the content of the mentioned log file? Possibly on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ if it's long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what did you do exactly?
did you tried to install ubuntu with wubi?

anyways, I recommend you to install ubuntu (or to try it first) by creating an bootable usb stick.

1. [Download the iso image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
2. [create bootable usb stick:](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
3. reboot and start ubuntu. 
   *On my laptop, I've to press F12 during the first seconds of startup to boot from an USB-Device. Then I can select USB Device as the bootable medium and the Ubuntu Version on my USB-Device is booting.*
4. now you can try ubuntu or install it, following [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-long-term-support)

I think this is the best way to try or to install ubuntu! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A Wubi-installation is rather simple:

- download (in Windows) the installer and excecute it
- the installer does it's thing and downloads your ubuntu-system
- Let the proces run until it's finished
- restart your computer and select in a tekst-mode Ubuntu to start up
- enjoy Ubuntu ! (first run updates before you do anything else)

This is the easiest way for having Ubuntu with the WUBI-method.

A side note: a Wubi-installation isn't as powerfull as a full (dualboot) installation of Ubuntu. But it gives you an impression of what to expect. Advisable is to do a dualboot for having Ubuntu at it's full speed. Another downside is: when Windows breaks up, you lose your Ubuntu-installation as well (keep in mind).